# How do you make your programme keep track of the amount of input you are putting in

Tags: java

I'm using
int moves = StdIn.readInt();
And I would like to know what code to use to make my program keep track of the amount of input and not the actual input. So when I'm playing a board game. I need the amount of moves printed out at the end of the game. Its between 3 and 64. But I'm unsure of how to code it. I'm using java. And eclipse. Please help.

Comment: You could use a counter and increase it once every turn, then print its value at the very end

Comment: Could you please show how by code. This is my first year doing java. The course is really doing the most

Comment: could you specify what `moves` (or `move` as in another comment) is? Is it the player move at the current turn?

Comment: So I'm creating a boardgame where the player just places colors in the 8×8 board and avoid certain patterns. Using move = StdIn.readInt(); for moves like 0 to delete row and 1 to place a color and 2 to quit. But I want to keep track of the moves. So everytime you choose either of that (mostly number 1) I want the programme to give the amount of moves. So let's say 18 colors out of the 64 were place before the people lost. I want to get the 18 as the amount of moves made

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a counter variable. Something like int numMoves = 0; Then, after every move, you can increment this by 1 by doing: numMoves++;

Comment: I get that. But I dont see the connection from that code to int move = StdIn.readInt();